# ios facebook ad sdk crash, FBAdCache.m line 528 -[FBAdCache defaultImageContext]

Tags: facebook

## 0

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000200
Raw Text
0
CoreImage
CI::GLContext::init() + 276
1   CoreImage
CI::GLContext::init() + 240
2   CoreImage
CI::GLContext::GLContext(CI::GLContext::ShareContextInfo, CGColorSpace*, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat, bool, unsigned long, bool, bool) + 468
3   CoreImage
CI::GLContext::GLContext(CI::GLContext::ShareContextInfo, CGColorSpace*, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat, bool, unsigned long, bool, bool) + 24
4   CoreImage
+[CIContext(Internal) internalContextWithEAGLContext:options:] + 808
5   CoreImage
-[CIContext initWithOptions:] + 816
6
CoreImage
+[CIContext contextWithOptions:] + 52
7   MyApp
FBAdCache.m line 528
-[FBAdCache defaultImageContext]
8   MyApp
FBAdImageMetalRenderer.m line 67
-[FBAdImageMetalRenderer initWithMTLDevice:]
9   MyApp
FBAdBlurredImageView.m line 158
-[FBAdBlurredImageView metalImageRenderer:]
10  MyApp
FBAdBlurredImageView.m line 138
-[FBAdBlurredImageView createImageRenderer]
11  MyApp
FBAdBlurredImageView.m line 113
-[FBAdBlurredImageView setupViewsWithImage:withBlurredImage:]
12  MyApp
FBAdBlurredImageView.m line 268
-[FBAdBlurredImageView updateView:]
13  MyApp
FBAdBlurredImageView.m line 257
-[FBAdBlurredImageView layoutSubviews]
14
UIKit
-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1256
15  QuartzCore
-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
16  QuartzCore
CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 332
17
UIKit
-[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 548

Comment: Yep, I got the same crash here. Do you have any update on this?

Comment: sorry, bro. i have not find the solution yet.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue, any solution